# Connection pool with the fog gem?

Tags: fog

I notice that the fog gem takes a long time to connect to Amazon S3 and upload the files. 
Is it possible to use a connection pool gem with fog? So it reduces the time the Sidekiq takes to upload the files.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Definitely, e.g. https://github.com/mperham/connection_pool - note this gem requires self-healing connections. I am not sure if this is your case.

Edit: I misinterpreted the question, if you ask about connection pooling of the fog object itself, that might not work correctly.